# How to bevel an edge evenly?

Tags: modeling, bevel

[image]When I try to bevel this edge one side is much longer than the other. I realize this is because the rectangle is much longer than how tall it is but I want to be able to evenly bevel it? Can someone help me

Comment: Apply the scale of the object

Comment: I think it might have to do with your cube's scale. I am a complete noob with regard to Blender but I made a one minute video on this that I think might help you. You can find it here. https://youtu.be/TPnPrXPS1-k

Comment: @Ray An honest mistake, I must have overlooked the yellow duplicate box.